# При разрешении экрана строка не переносится

Tags: css

В общем если сменить разрешение на 1680, то ссылка не переносится на другую строку в окне, а при 1920 все норм. Как сделать, чтобы ссылка переносилась на другую строку?

```css
@media (max-width: 1920px) {
    .info_box_0 > div > div:first-child,
    .info_box_1 > div > div:first-child,
    .info_box_2 > div > div:first-child,
    .info_box_3 > div > div:first-child,
    .box > div > div:first-child {
        min-width: 120px;
        max-width: 120px;
    }

    .protocol-info-header {
        min-width: 120px!important;
        max-width: 120px!important;
    }

    .info_box_2 > div:first-child > div:first-child {
        min-width: 120px;
        max-width: 120px;
    }

    .head-title-chat-essence > div > div {
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    .name-image-file > div:first-child {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        white-space: pre;
    }

    .message_body .name-image-file > div:first-child {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        max-width: 300px;
        white-space: pre;
    }

    .section-teaching-users_сommunicationAsMessenger .arrow {
        right: -409px!important;
        top: 130px!important;
    }

    .section-teaching-users.section-teaching-users_feedBack .section-teaching-users_2_1 {
        top: 215px;
    }

    .section-teaching-users.section-teaching-users_hierarchy .arrow {
        right: -325px!important;
        top: 42px!important;
    }

    .section-teaching-users.section-teaching-users_hierarchy .section-teaching-users_1_1 {
        left: 14px;
    }

    .attachment_message_read {
        width: 238px;
    }

}
```

Comment: У вас не рабочий пример, переделайте пожалуйста. И так же посоветовал бы в css избавиться от !important

Answer (score 1):

проблему решил, заключалась в word-break, т.е. добавил word-break: break-all и все встало на место.